# How to save changes in /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf?

Tags: command-line, initramfs

I do not have enough storage on boot to update my version of Ubuntu, »sudo apt autoremove« did not help. Therefore I wanted to put "Compress=xz" in »/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf«.

Unfortunately I do not know how to save this change and would be glad for help.
Thank you!
[screenshot of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZikC9.png)

Comment: look at your image STR+o saves it and STR+x you can leave the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Do `sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` and alter the line

```
COMPRESS=zstd
```

to

```
COMPRESS=xz
```

control-o (Speichern=save) to saved changes and then rebuild with

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```